# How to fix WSL domain resolution

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

so I was having issues with domain resolution with WSL whenever I use the VPN. I would get this:

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I tried following instructions from these answers [Temporary Failure in name resolution on WSL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192347/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-on-wsl?newreg=59c21ddd3c93441fba6a3b9da4e1dc62)

Specifically from this part:

> 1. Inside WSL2, create or append file: /etc/wsl.conf
> 2. Put the following lines in the file in order to ensure the your DNS changes do not get blown away
>
>    ```
>    echo "[network]" | sudo tee /etc/wsl.conf
>    echo "generateResolvConf = false" | sudo tee -a /etc/wsl.conf
>    ```
> 3. **In a cmd window**, run `wsl --shutdown`
> 4. Start WSL2
> 5. Run the following inside WSL2
>
>    ```
>    sudo rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
>    sudo cat << EOF > /etc/resolv.conf
>    search [yourbase.domain.local]
>    nameserver 8.8.8.8
>    nameserver 1.1.1.1
>    EOF
>    ```

However, I cannot seem to be able to edit the file /etc/resolv.conf as I would get `zsh: permission denied: /etc/resolv.conf`

I also don't know what it means [yourbase.domain.local] or with what I should be replacing it. I already messed up my domain resolution, and now I get the first error every time, even when my laptop is not connected to the VPN. I really need to know how to fix the config files that I modified

Edit: using muru's suggestion from the comments, I was able to fix the domain resolution with the command

```
sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf <<EOF
```

However, I'd like to know if there is a solution for this error when I connect to a VPN. Since none of the solutions from the mentioned link didn't work for me.

Comment: The permission denied part is easily fixed: `sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf <<EOF` instead of `sudo cat << EOF > /etc/resolv.conf`. If you don't know your search domain, just omit that line.

Comment: @muru thanks, I should've checked what "tee" does. it's working now. However, do you know how I can solve the issue of domain resolution once I connect to the VPN? Some of the answers didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: When the VPN is connected in Windows, can you access services by IP in WSL2?  For instance, can you `ping 8.8.8.8` successfully when connected to the VPN?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I cant either. I get package losses. I'm kinda trying to follow this tutorial https://jamespotz.github.io/blog/how-to-fix-wsl2-and-cisco-vpn but its still not working for me either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's a different potential solution than I've seen before, but it's worked for some folks.  I'm no longer on Cisco VPN, so I can't test it, but ...

There are two parts to resolving the issue:

- Fix Internet Connectivity
- Fix DNS resolution

In the comments, you confirmed that you also can't `ping 8.8.8.8`, which may mean that you haven't resolved the first part.  However, I do see in [this Github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277#issuecomment-948363691) that `ping` just won't work at all with some AnyConnect settings, so perhaps that's not the best indicator.

Try:

```
wget https://$(powershell.exe -c "(Resolve-DnsName -type a askubuntu.com)[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress" | tr -d '\r')
```

That's going to use PowerShell to resolve the IP Address for Ask Ubuntu, then attempt to `wget` from it.  It should fail, but you should get back:

```
ERROR: cannot verify 151.101.129.69's certificate, issued by ‘CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
...
```

If not, then you probably really haven't resolve the *connection* issue.  And until that is fixed, DNS resolution definitely won't work.

Try the 4th command there:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
```

Then try the `wget` above again.  Any difference?

If not, then try (in this order):

- Exit Ubuntu
- Disconnect AnyConnect
- `wsl --shutdown` from POwerShell
- Start Ubuntu
- Connect to AnyConnect
- Run (again):

  In PowerShell:

  ```
  Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
  ```

  In Ubuntu:

  ```
  wget https://$(powershell.exe -c "(Resolve-DnsName -type a askubuntu.com)[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress" | tr -d '\r')
  ```

If you do then have Internet connection, then follow the rest of the steps to try to fix the DNS resolution.

But for some users, this continues to be a problem.

Also see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/machuu/7663aa653828d81efbc2aaad6e3b1431) for what *may* be a better guide.  It's the same overall information, but slightly different order and implementation.

###### Possible Alternative - Run Ubuntu in WSL1

If your use-case for WSL supports it, WSL1 will typically run without issues when connect to a VPN.  You can convert the instance from PowerShell via:

```
wsl -l -v
# Confirm distribution name, adjust commands as needed
wsl --export Ubuntu \windows\path\to\save\ubuntu.tar
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1
```

Or, if you'd like, you can `wsl --import` that backup into a new instance WSL1 instance via `wsl --import UbuntuWSL1 \location\for\instance \path\to\ubuntu.tar --version 1`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've disabled **Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)** in **WLAN Properties** of **Network Connections** Settings.

Configuration Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Disabling Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)]

Ping GitHub.com Successfully Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Ping GitHub.com Successfully]

Source:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/628767/338681